# Blender USD model doesn't create shadow

Tags: modeling, lighting, shadows

I exported two Blender (ver 3.6.0) models into two USD ones. They all don't have any internal light. I show them in my program with a directional light source. It is a surprise that one (the chess piece) created a shadow but the other (the device) did not. For the device model, the Shadow box in the Material/Settings is opaque and the Shadown box in the View port is checked.

How do we fix the problem with the device model?

[image: The device model has no shadow]

[image: Settings]